# Why MatchTemplate from EmguCV/OpenCV don't work on another images that have the same template in it?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Basically, I am doing a console application using Emgu CV to find out a template. It's a project to auto correct an answer sheet with a smartphone photo. It works fine with my photo 1, as the next image shows (it uses green to indicates A and blue to indicates B):

[Answer sheet 1 - Working pretty fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf6rb.jpg)

The problem is when I try to use another photography, it don't find out the A and B answers. Like it shows in the next image:

[Answer sheet 2 - Not identified nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRvSF.jpg)

I couldn't find anything on how I can do this, but I identified something that causes the problem:

- Taking the photo on another smartphone other than mine;
- Photos with different width and height than the one I used to make the template;
- Taking the photo with another light different from the templates.

Here follows my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ocrTesseract = new IronTesseract();
    ocrTesseract.Language = OcrLanguage.Financial;
    ocrTesseract.Configuration.PageSegmentationMode = TesseractPageSegmentationMode.SingleChar;

    string cartaoRespondidoPath = "C:\\Users\\Fernando\\source\\repos\\ConsoleEmguCV_folha2\\ConsoleEmguCV\\img\\respondido_manual_1.jpeg";
    Image<Bgr, Byte> cartaoRespondido = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(cartaoRespondidoPath);
    Image<Bgr, Byte> respostaA = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("C:\\Users\\Fernando\\source\\repos\\ConsoleEmguCV_folha2\\ConsoleEmguCV\\img\\respondido_manual_template_a.png");
    Image<Bgr, Byte> respostaB = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("C:\\Users\\Fernando\\source\\repos\\ConsoleEmguCV_folha2\\ConsoleEmguCV\\img\\respondido_manual_template_b.png");

    Mat templateOutput = new Mat();

    CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(cartaoRespondido, respostaA, templateOutput, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

    double minVal = 0.0d;
    double maxVal = 0.0d;
    System.Drawing.Point minLoc = new System.Drawing.Point();
    System.Drawing.Point maxLoc = new System.Drawing.Point();

    CvInvoke.MinMaxLoc(templateOutput, ref minVal, ref maxVal, ref minLoc, ref maxLoc);

    CvInvoke.Threshold(templateOutput, templateOutput, 0.69, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.ToZero);


    var matches = templateOutput.ToImage<Gray, Byte>();
    string befNumber = "0";

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matches.Cols; j++)
        {
            if (matches[i, j].Intensity > .68)
            {
                using(var ocrInput = new OcrInput())
                {
                    System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(j, i);
                    System.Drawing.Rectangle box = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(loc, respostaA.Size);
                    
                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(cartaoRespondido, box, new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                    ocrInput.AddImage(cartaoRespondidoPath, new CropRectangle(x: loc.X, y: loc.Y, width: 25, height: 30)); ;

                    var numero = ocrTesseract.Read(ocrInput);
                    string numeroFinal = new string(numero.Text.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
                    if (!numeroFinal.Equals(befNumber))
                    {
                        befNumber = numeroFinal;
                        Console.WriteLine("Resposta " + numeroFinal + " A");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(cartaoRespondido, respostaB, templateOutput, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

    CvInvoke.Threshold(templateOutput, templateOutput, 0.69, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.ToZero);

    matches = templateOutput.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
    befNumber = "0";

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matches.Cols; j++)
        {
            if (matches[i, j].Intensity > .68)
            {
                using(var ocrInput = new OcrInput())
                {
                    System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(j, i);
                    System.Drawing.Rectangle box = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(loc, respostaB.Size);

                    CvInvoke.Rectangle(cartaoRespondido, box, new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

                    ocrInput.AddImage(cartaoRespondidoPath, new CropRectangle(x: loc.X, y: loc.Y, width: 25, height: 30)); ;

                    var numero = ocrTesseract.Read(ocrInput);
                    string numeroFinal = new string(numero.Text.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
                    if (!numeroFinal.Equals(befNumber))
                    {
                        befNumber = numeroFinal;
                        Console.WriteLine("Resposta " + numeroFinal + " B");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CvInvoke.Imwrite("respostas.png", cartaoRespondido);
}
```

And here are my templates: [Template for answer A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drsNQ.png), [Template for answer B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjCGH.png)

I tried to change from `Image<Bgr, Byte>` to `Mat` but it didn't worked. I also tried to transform the image to grayscale.